# Как добавить в метод .Post() функцию возвращающее html разметку.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Помогите разобраться третий день бьюсь!

Есть у меня на странице всплывающий список с размерами одежды. В зависимости от выбранного размера должна меняться цена товара на странице. Для работы с БД я использую entity framrework. С помощью jquery cоздал обработчик события пр изменении значения в списке. Что нужно ввести в function(data), чтобы вернуть html разметку с ценой на страницу.

Вот сам обработчик события change()

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#IdSize').change(function () {
        var idS = $('#IdSize').val();
        var urlPrice = '@Url.Action("GetPriceForSize")';
        $.post(urlPrice,
        { idProd: '@Model.Product.IdProduct',
            idSize: idS
        },
         function(data) {
     ............................
   });

});
```

Это partitial view GetPriceForSize:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetPriceForSize(int idProd, int idSize)
        {
            Prices price = repository.Prices.
                Where(p => p.IdProd == idProd && p.IdSize == idSize).
                SingleOrDefault();

            return Json(new { price = price.Price });
        }

@model haengematten.eu.Models.Prices

     <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-67_clone">
          <span class="price">@Model.Price</span>                
     </span>
```

Помогите разобраться, только начал jquery изучать.

`

Comment: Нормальный вопрос. Зачем его закрывать?

Comment: я его и не закрывал, не помню, чтобы делал это. Спасибо за ответы))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может не совсем верно понял вопрос. Но есть такое решение. Всегда им пользуюсь.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    // метод передачи данных скрипту
    url: "url",
    // адрес скрипта
    data: data,
    // передаваемые параметры (обычная POST/GET запись)
    beforeSend: function (html) {},
    // то, что будет выполняться до передачи
    success: function (html) { // то, что будет выполняться после успешной передачи
        $("body").append(html); // в данном случае на страницу добавляется то, что было "выведено на печать" в скрипте, куда передавались данные
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

намного понятнее, когда все Url`ы указываются явно, на мой взгляд лучше не лезть в js серверным кодом. Можете попробовать вместо `return Json(new { price = price.Price });` использовать `return PartialView("GetPriceForSize", price);` и если в $.post dataType установлен в html, то всё должно сработать

---

и ещё вместо `SingleOrDefault();` используйте `FirstOrDefault();`, он вытянет из базы только одно значение, в то время как первый вытянет все, и уже в памяти будет искать первый елемент

вот во что маппиться `SingleOrDefault()`

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Name], [t0].[Description]
FROM [Sections] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Id] = @p0
```

а вот `FirstOrDefault()`

```
SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[Id], [t0].[Name], [t0].[Description]
FROM [Sections] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Id] = @p0
```